# How should I share code ("modules") between my templates?

Tags: python, templates, module, pylons

If I had two controllers in my Pylons website that server up two different template files, what would be the best way to show the same piece of HTML on each template?

For example, lets say I had a blog. The front page would show the list of recent entries and each entry would have a 'permanent link' linking to a page showing just that entry. On each of those pages, I want to show 'latest entries' - A list of the 5 most recent blog posts.

The template files different. The controllers are different. How do I show the 'latest posts module' ?

Should I just have something like:

```
from blog.model import posts

class BlogController(BaseController):

    def index(self):
        c.latestPosts = posts.get_latest()

        return render('home.html')

class OtherController(BaseController):

    def index(self):
        c.latestPosts = posts.get_latest()

        return render('otherpage.html')
```

`c.latestPosts` would then be a list of links that the template renders. The problem I see with this is, I have to render the HTML for this on two separate template files. If I want to change the HTML, it means changing it in two places...

I'm trying to come up with a neat way to do this but I'm running out of ideas. How would you do it?

Answer (score 2):

Being able to share common HTML fragments like headers, footers, "logged in" area of page, sidebars etc. is a very common requirement. Template engines usually provide means for this.

If you're using Mako, here are the two main mechanisms you can use:

#### Includes

Check out the [<%include>](http://www.makotemplates.org/docs/syntax.html#syntax_tags_include) tag. In your page template you specify where various reusable bits would be placed. You kind of build the page from ground up, assemble it from the reusable components you have.

Example from Mako documentation:

```
<%include file="header.html"/>

    hello world

<%include file="footer.html"/>
```

#### Inheritance

Check out the [<%inherit>](http://www.makotemplates.org/docs/syntax.html#syntax_tags_inherit) tag. This works similarly to inheritance in programming languages like Python. In a base template you set up a skeleton of the page. In page templates you customize and extend some parts of the base template.

Quick example, `base.mako`:

```
<html>
<head></head> 
<body>
    ${self.header()}

    ${self.body()}

</body>
</html>

<%def name="header()">

This is the common header all pages will get unless 
they override this.

</%def>
```

And `somepage.mako`:

```
<%inherit file="/base.mako"/>

This content will go into body of base.
```

Template engines usually have many nifty features, and I encourage you to get to know them well!

Answer (score 0):

Although Pēteris' answer is good, you may also be looking for **[Mako's <%namespace> functionality](http://www.makotemplates.org/docs/syntax.html#syntax_tags_namespace)**, which closely parallels the "import" statement in raw Python.

However, <%inherit> and <%include> are also things that you should find yourself using regularly.